# Rectangular bounding boxes around objects in monochrome images in python?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have a set of two monochrome images [attached] where I want to put rectangular bounding boxes for both the persons in each image. I understand that cv2.dilate may help, but most of the examples I see are focusing on detecting one rectangle containing the maximum pixel intensities, so essentially they put one big rectangle in the image. I would like to have two separate rectangles.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

**UPDATE:**
This is my attempt:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('splinet.png',0)
print im.shape
kernel = np.ones((50,50),np.uint8)
dilate = cv2.dilate(im,kernel,iterations = 10)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,0)
im3,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
plt.imshow(im,cmap='Greys_r')
#plt.imshow(im3,cmap='Greys_r')

for i in range(0, len(contours)):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
       cnt = contours[i]
       #mask = np.zeros(im2.shape,np.uint8)
       #cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt],0,255,-1)
       x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
       cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),5)
       plt.imshow(im,cmap='Greys_r')
       cv2.imwrite(str(i)+'.png', im)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the output is attached below: As you see, small boxes are being made and its not super clear too.

[image: output]

Comment: ***'most of the examples'*** what do mean by this? And what is it that you want?

Comment: I mean that the tutorials I find online foucs on detecting one rectangle containing the maximum pixel intensities. I want to put bounding boxes on both the persons in both the images

Comment: As a starting point you should search for `contour bounding box binary image` and get some code here, The idea is to threshold the images and find contours and then bounding boxes

Comment: @ZdaR done that! The output is messy.

Comment: Adjust the threshold value from 127 to something lower as 10-20

Comment: How are you obtaining these images in the first place? Is it from another image or a video frame? if it's an image can you upload it?

Comment: @JeruLuke the image come from a cascade of processes, and the image I attached is the final output. I have to use the final output only

Comment: @GKS Were you able to arrive at a conclusion? how is the progress?

Comment: @JeruLuke : Hi , I managed to get the desired results in these images using 8 connected components. But, I could not generalize the strategy for all the images, and I had to give up

Comment: @GKS No problem

Answer (score 0):

The real problem in your question lies in ***selection of the optimal threshold*** from the monochrome image.

In order to do that, calculate the median of the gray scale image (the second image in your post). The **threshold** level will be set **33%** above this median value. Any value below this **threshold** will be binarized.

This is what I got:

[image]

Now performing morphological dilation followed by contour operations you can highlight your region of interest with a rectangle.

***Note:***

Never set a manual threshold as you did. Threshold can vary for different images. Hence always opt for a threshold based on the **median** of the image.

Comment: still getting one rectangle for each person is not happening. It gives one rectangle only for the person on the right

Comment: approximation is your best bet, given an image like this